# Sorting the dependencies tree in java

Tags: java, maven, ant, dependencies, graph-theory

I have a list of libraries. They use Maven, Ant or Gradle as a builder.

I've created two `Map<String, Set<String>>` objects. The first map has `libraryName` and `Set` of resulting artifacts, the second map has `libraryName` and `Set` of its first-level dependencies.

Some libraries depend on each other.

So here's my problem:
I need to sort all the libraries by their dependencies on each other, from those which doesn't depend on others to the most dependent ones.

Comment: What is the particular problem here?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm stuck sorting the libraries by dependencies. I need a list where the first item will be the library, that should be build first, because it doesn't depend on any other library in my list, and the list item will be the library, that need to be built last, as it depends on many other libraries.

Comment: Already answered by @JF Maier topological sorting is the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your libraries form a graph of dependencies, where an arc from A to B means "A depends on B". You need to sort the graph so that no library depends on one later in the list. This order is a topological sorting

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

and can be achieved e.g. by Kahn's algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That helped!